# Building my own database of Facebook posts by calling Graph API via Server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to build my own database of Facebook posts by periodically calling the Facebook Graph API and saving the results. User would then communicate with my own database instead of directly with Facebook.

I know that the API calls require an Access token that is generated from your Facebook login. From what I understand, this means the user logging in on the clientside would be using their own access token to make the calls. However, I want to make the calls from the server, **which means using my own access token.**

To illustrate the process flow:

```
*SERVER*
myFBAccessToken ---(API call every 15 mins)---> Facebook ---(returns)---> Fb posts ---(save to)---> myDatabase

*CLIENT* 
viewFbPosts ---(db call)---> myDatabase
```

**My questions are:

----------------------

1. Is it possible to use a single access token to regularly call the API from server? (Every 15 mins) 

2. Will doing so violate any usage limitations on how frequently you can call the API? 

3. Does Facebook allow for storing of their content on external databases?**

Alternatively, if this is not recommended, does anyone know of a way to get more than the latest 25 posts from the facebook /feed?

I am using MEAN stack (mongodb, expressjs, angularjs, nodejs) with asynchronous functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, you can use the same token for the same user multiple times. However, once it expires, you will have to re-login your user again to get a new access token.
2. There is not an official limitation of number of queries that you are sending to graph API. However, being involved in this sphere for a long time, I found out that 1 query per 1 second is workable for a single user. If you try to exceed it, you will most probably get JSON with error.
3. You do not have to notify facebook that you are going to store its data in external database. You simply get permitted information using graph API and, afterwards, it is totally up to you what you are going to do with the data. Facebook is responsible for flow of the data from their servers and making sure that you are the person who has a right to get that information on a legal basis.

Comment: Awesome! Do you happen to know how I can re-login back to Facebook periodically? I am thinking of setting an interval to repeat. Any tips?

Comment: Login procedure must be done only by a user. However, you can get long-lived tokens, which can be valid for up to 60 days. You might find this helpful: `https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension`

Comment: Yes I was just reading that documentation. So if I wanted my app to periodically make calls, it must depend on a user to login in order to have the correct token? Would I be able to run the SERVER process illustrated in my question above?

Comment: Your calls to the graph API depend directly on the access token of the user. However, your user will not always see OAuth window asking him/her to login again if the app is opened again next day. On the contrary, your app will get a `signed_request`, which will contain `access_token` for this particular user and it should be extracted(parsed). To get the `signed_request` you will have to use your `app_id` and `app_secret` while making a GET query.  Everything will happen quickly, so that your user will be logged in simultaneously once the your app opens.